# Python compiler got stuck on panda processing

Tags: python-3.x, logistic-regression

I don't know why my compiler got stuck when I run the function **a,b,c=grad(t0,t1,t2)**. On running this line the whole program got stopped. I also tried to use debugger(**pdb**) but when I reach that line the debugger also stops working.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

data=pd.read_csv('Social_Network_Ads.csv')
data_temp=data[:]

x_train=data.iloc[0:300,2:4].values
y_train=data.iloc[0:300,4].values

x_test=data.iloc[300:,2:4].values
y_test=data.iloc[300:,4].values

al=0.1
t0,t1,t2=1,1,1

def grad(z0,z1,z2):
    i=0
    s0,s1,s2=0,0,0
    while i<3:
        z=-(z0+z1*x_train[i][0]+z2*x_train[i][1])
        s0=s0+(1/(1+math.exp(z))-y_train[i])
        s1=s1+((1/(1+math.exp(z))-y_train[i])*x_train[i][0])
        s2=s2+((1/(1+math.exp(z))-y_train[i])*x_train[i][1])
        i+i+1
    z0=z0-al*s0
    z1=z1-al*s1
    z2=z2-al*s2
    return z0,z1,z2    

j=0
while j<5:
    a,b,c=grad(t0,t1,t2)
    t0,t1,t2=a,b,c
    print(t0,t1,t2)
    j=j+1
```

Comment: What is the compiler error you're seeing?

Comment: (in python we usually talk about the python _interpreter_, even though sure, there is some compilation that happens behind the scenes to improve performance)